# While using product flavours what files are common in each flavour and what files are specific to that flavour?

Tags: android, localization

```
productFlavors {
        India {

        }
        USA {

        }
    }
```

Lets take 2 product flavours for an example

**1. India 
2. USA**

total number of build variants will be 4

**1. IndiaDebug
2. IndiaRelease
3. USADebug
4. USARelease**

Which files are common for all flavours and which files are flavour specific as well as debug and release specific ?

If localization is supported and if english is common language for India and USA then each build will have separate english file or common file ?

Comment: Each flavour can have there own res files. So If you can choose a different set of strings.xml files for India and USA. provided that you have not used hardcoded strings in you ui

Answer (score 1):

Product Flavour is a awesome solution to build different varieties of the same application with individual features.

**Specific Files**

Say like , one of your Activity will have different functionality and UI, then you can avoid keeping that Activity in common package and move to respective flavour. Each flavour can have separate `java` and `res` folder along with Manifest (which is not mandatory, Studio take care of itself).  It is here your specific Activity's java file and xml file should be placed.

*Example* :  Login Screen will have different UI and features in each flavour

Now during runtime as well as compile time, Android Studio switches between the packages and picks suitable files. This is done through `Build Variant` feature

[image]

**Common Files**

So coming to common files which is applicable is all the flavours, let it be in `main/java` and `main/res` itself.

Ideally depending on your flavour numbers, bundle.gradle will look similar to this.

```
productFlavors {

        student {
            applicationId "com.abc.student"
        }
        staff {
            applicationId "com.abc.staff"
        }
        tempstaff {
            applicationId "com.abc.tempstaff"
        }
    }
sourceSets {
        tempstaff {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/tempstaff/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
        student{
            manifest.srcFile 'src/student/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
        staff {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/staff/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
    }
```

> Now to conclude the answer, files which are common throughout the
>   application will remain in the `main` package. Specific files
>   applicable to separate flavour will go in that flavour. This means
>   flavours can have extra Activity/Features that are not at all a part
>   of others including main also

Go through [this link](http://blog.brainattica.com/how-to-work-with-flavours-on-android/) for more information.