# Android compile 2 apks from 1 source

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am using Android Studio and have built an app.  I would like to make a clone of the app but with some slight changes such as the app name, and a few alternative images.

So app 1 would be called "My App 1" and have a specific app logo and the SplashActivity would show app 1's logo, and my second app would be called "My App 2" and respectively it will have a different app logo and different logo on the SpashActivity. All the underlying code in the app stays the same at this time.

Instead of having 2 entirely separate projects with 2 almost cloned source codes, I was hoping that a could have 1 project and some sort of way to create 2 apk's when it is compiled.  This will allow me to modify and improve my source code, yet when I compile it I know both apps are still functioning the same.

Can anyone shed some light on how to achieve this?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#product-flavors

Comment: You need to read this link [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html) . It contains all the information actually what you wanted to achieved can be done through **Create Source Sets for Build Variants**

Comment: You can go through this as well.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40302977/while-using-product-flavours-what-files-are-common-in-each-flavour-and-what-file/40303385#40303385