# Is there any possibility to generate cloned apk without changing package name?

Tags: android, apk

My application is based on local storage(SQLite) stuff. This is based on two different users. When user A login for the first time, data will be stored internally including login details. If the user B login to the same application it won't allow it. So I need to clear local storage to allow B user to login. My question is: is there any way to create two apk without changing PACKAGE NAME?
Note: This is for testing purpose. I want to check my application without clearing local storage.

Comment: Yes there is a way, learn about the Product Flavor. 
Go with this link.
http://www.technoblogpost.com/product-flavors/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41643311/three-product-flavors-two-very-similar-one-smaller-but-different/41647706#41647706